# error unmarshalling soap in delphi 10

Tags: web-services, delphi, soap, wsdl

I am testing a delphi 10 soap program.
I did import the wsdl (soap 12) as a separate unit. no pb on importing with the wizard default parameters. (similar to old versions of delphi)
when running a call to a specific function I have this error message:

### `Debugger Exception Notification

Project WebapiConfigServices.exe raised exception class ERemotableException with message 'Unmarshalling Error: unrecognized type name: StringAssetInfo. Did you mean {http://metadataservice.services.xxxx.com}StringAssetInfo? '.`

I tried different options to import the WSDL, as discussed in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884560/unmarshalling-error)

didn't help.
SOAPUI or python call are working.

seems that the program receive the XML answer but doesn't know how to manipulate the object 'StringAssetInfo'.

I don't find a right way to debug the software. Is there a specific function I can put a breakpoint?

is there any other solution I can test?

does someone know an external library to build a right wrapper around the wsdl (soap 1.2) ?

thanks for your help

se